# Agregar color sólido o imagen como fondo en una aplicación

Tags: python, python-2.7, formularios, tkinter

Llevo ya un tiempo aprendiendo con Python, encontré un código de un formulario y ahora quiero colocarle fondo. El primer problema es que solo me aparece la ventana y no me aparece el formulario y no se que hago mal.

Por otro lado, quiero como digo colocar el fondo ya sea imagen o color e ir colocando los campos para llenar y así realizar el formulario.

Este es mi código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
TkForm - Formularios en Tkinter con tk.Entry y ttk.Combobox
Copyleft 2014, Carlos Zayas Guggiari <carlos@zayas.org>
"""
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk


class Campo(object):
"""Clase para definir cada campo del formulario."""

    def __init__(self, padre, linea, etiqueta, tipo, valor, modo=False):
        self.padre = padre
        self.linea = linea
        self.etiqueta = etiqueta
        self.valor = tk.StringVar()
        self.etiqueta = tk.Label(padre, text=etiqueta)
        self.etiqueta.grid(column=0, row=linea)
        tipos = {'combobox': self.combobox,
                 'entry': self.entry}
        tipos[tipo](valor, modo)

    def entry(self, valor, modo=False):
        self.ent = tk.Entry(self.padre, textvariable=self.valor)
        self.valor.set(valor)
        self.ent.grid(column=1, row=self.linea)

    def combobox(self, valor, modo=False):
        estado = 'readonly' if modo else 'normal'
        self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.padre,
                            textvariable=self.valor,
                            state=estado)
        self.box['values'] = valor
        self.box.current(0)  # Selecciona el primer elemento de la tupla.
        self.box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.combobox_elegir)
        self.box.grid(column=1, row=self.linea)

    def combobox_elegir(self, evento):
        self.valor.set(self.box.get())


class Formulario(object):
    """Clase para definir un conjunto de campos."""

    def __init__(self, padre, campos):
        self.padre = padre
        self.campos = {}
        self.guardar = False
        linea = 0
        for campo in campos:
            etiqueta, tipo, valor, modo = campo
            self.campos[etiqueta] = Campo(padre, linea,
                                      etiqueta, tipo, valor, modo)
            linea += 1
        self.btnacep = tk.Button(padre, text="Aceptar", command=self.aceptar)
        self.btncanc = tk.Button(padre, text="Cancelar", command=self.cancelar)
        self.btnacep.grid(column=1, row=linea, sticky='W')
        self.btncanc.grid(column=1, row=linea, sticky='E')

    def aceptar(self):
        self.guardar = True
        self.padre.destroy()

    def cancelar(self):
        self.padre.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raiz = tk.Tk()
    frame = Frame(raiz)
    frame.pack()

    bottomframe = Frame(raiz)
    bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )
    raiz.geometry('1364x700+0+0')
    raiz.configure(bg = 'white')
    raiz.title('Dr. Juan Suarez')
    #self.raiz.destroy
    salir=ttk.Button(frame, text='Ingresar',command=raiz.destroy).pack(side=RIGHT,fill=BOTH, expand=True,padx=5,pady=5)
    form = Formulario(raiz, [
                         ["Nombre", "entry", "", False],
                         ["Direccion", "entry", "", False],
                         ["CC:","entry","", False],
                         ["Tipo", "combobox", ['O+', 'O-','B', 'AB','A-','A+'],
                          True],
                         ["Numero", "entry", "(+57)", False]
                        ])
    raiz.mainloop()
    if form.guardar:
        for campo in form.campos:
            print campo, form.campos[campo].valor.get()
```

Comment: Tienes un error importante, no puedes mezclar en Tkinter los métodos `grid` y `pack` sobre una misma raiz. En tu caso creas `frame` y usas `pack` para posicionarlo dentro de la ventana principal. Sobre esa mism a ventana principal se crea el formulario (`form = Formulario(raiz,...)`) , pero `Campo` posiciona usando `grid`. Este es el error que hay, para poder ayudarte más deberias explicar cual debe ser el comportamiento de tu app. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo que quiero que suceda es que le pueda colocar el fondo ya sea imagen o color e ir colocando los campos para llenar y asi realizar el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa de que no se muestre el formulario se debe a que **no puedes mezclar en Tkinter los métodos `grid` y `pack` sobre una misma ventana principal**. En tu caso creas `frame` y usas `pack` para posicionarlo dentro de la ventana principal pero luego, sobre esa misma ventana principal, se crea el formulario (`form = Formulario(raiz,...))` , pero `Campo` posiciona usando `grid`.

En lo relativo a agregar fondos en Tkinter por norma general vamos a diferenciar dos casos:

- **Color sólido:** En este caso basta con usar el atributo background o bg (son lo mismo) tal y como haces tu en aquellos wigets que lo soporten. Esto lo puedes hacer al instanciar o usando el método `configure`. El color se pasa o bién mediante su nombre (dentro de los nombres reconocidos por Tkinter) o usando el valor RGB en hexadecimal:

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk   # Python 2
  #import tkinter as tk  # Python 3

  top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black') # Usando nombre
  top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#FFB266") # Usando valor RGB
  top_frame.configure(bg='red') #Lo mismo pero usando el método configure
  ```
- **Usando imágenes o degradados:** En estos casos lo anterior no vale. La cosa se complica bastante más, en comparación a frameworks más complejos como Kivy, Qt o Gtk. Necesitamos cargar la imagen y usar generalmente un `Canvas` o un `Label` para agregarla. Posteriormente podemos usar el widget como base (Canvas) o posicionarlo al fondo del que tengamos mediante el método `place` o `pack`. Usando un `Canvas` podemos crear degradados de fondo si nos interesa.

  A la hora de cargar la imagen podemos usar la clase [`PhotoImage`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) si nuestra imagen tiene el formato GIF o PGM/PPM:

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk   # Python 2
  #import tkinter as tk  # Python 3


  root = tk.Tk()
  root.resizable(0, 0)

  # Esta referencia debe mantenerse mientra necesitemos el fondo
  background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"/ruta/imagen.png")

  w = background_image.width()
  h = background_image.height()

  root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(w, h, 0, 0))

  background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
  background_label.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
  root.mainloop()
  ```

  Si la imagen tiene otro formato necesitamos cargarla usando PIL (solo Python 2) o, mejor, su fork actualizado [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/4.1.1) (Python 2 y Python 3). Para esto primero hay que instalar la biblioteca como es lógico (por ejemplo mediante pip:

  ```
  $ python -m pip install pillow
  ```

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk   # Python 2
  #import tkinter as tk  # Python 3
  from PIL import Image, ImageTk


  root = tk.Tk()
  root.resizable(0, 0)

  image = Image.open (r"ruta/a/imagen")
  # Esta referencia debe mantenerse mientra necesitemos el fondo
  background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

  w = background_image.width()
  h = background_image.height()
  root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(w, h, 0, 0))

  background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
  background_label.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
  root.mainloop()
  ```

  Otro  problema es que el fondo no cambia de tamaño si la ventana lo hace, deberemos implementar esta funcionalidad por nosotros mismos. Lo más simple, es crear una clase que herede de `Frame` y añadir la opción de una imagen de fondo por defecto y los métodos para que se reescale de forma automática:

  ```
  import Tkinter as tk   # Python 2
  #import tkinter as tk  # Python 3
  from PIL import Image, ImageTk


  class BFrame(tk.Frame):
      def __init__(self, master, img, *args):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args)

          self.imagen = Image.open(img)
          self.copia_imagen= self.imagen.copy()
          self.imagen_de_fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagen)

          self.fondo = tk.Label(self, image=self.imagen_de_fondo)
          self.fondo.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
          self.fondo.bind('<Configure>', self._redimensionar)

      def _redimensionar(self,event):
          ancho = event.width
          alto = event.height
          self.imagen = self.copia_imagen.resize((ancho, alto))
          self.imagen_de_fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagen)
          self.fondo.configure(image =  self.imagen_de_fondo)
  ```

  El widget se instancia pesándole el padre y la ruta de la imagen de fondo:

  ```
  frame = BFrame(root, 'C/:Imágenes/fondo.jpg')
  ```

  Su uso es igual que cualquier `Frame`. Al usar `place` podemos usar posteriormente `grid` o `pack` para posicionar los widgets de forma indistinta.

Te dejo un ejemplo muy simple usando tu código. La ventana principal tiene un fondo sólido mientras que el formulario tiene una imagen de fondo usando la clase `BFrame` anterior:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

##### Python 2 #####
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

'''
##### Python 3 #####
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
''' 

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

"""
TkForm - Formularios en Tkinter con tk.Entry y ttk.Combobox
Copyleft 2014, Carlos Zayas Guggiari <carlos@zayas.org>
"""

class Campo(object):
    """Clase para definir cada campo del formulario."""

    def __init__(self, padre, linea, etiqueta, tipo, valor, modo=False):
        self.padre = padre
        self.linea = linea
        self.etiqueta = etiqueta
        self.valor = tk.StringVar()
        self.etiqueta = tk.Label(padre, text=etiqueta)
        self.etiqueta.grid(column=0, row=linea)
        tipos = {'combobox': self.combobox,
                 'entry': self.entry}
        tipos[tipo](valor, modo)

    def entry(self, valor, modo=False):
        self.ent = tk.Entry(self.padre, textvariable=self.valor)
        self.valor.set(valor)
        self.ent.grid(column=1, row=self.linea)

    def combobox(self, valor, modo=False):
        estado = 'readonly' if modo else 'normal'
        self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.padre,
                            textvariable=self.valor,
                            state=estado)
        self.box['values'] = valor
        self.box.current(0)  # Selecciona el primer elemento de la tupla.
        self.box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.combobox_elegir)
        self.box.grid(column=1, row=self.linea)

    def combobox_elegir(self, evento):
        self.valor.set(self.box.get())


class Formulario(object):
    """Clase para definir un conjunto de campos."""

    def __init__(self, padre, campos):
        self.padre = padre
        self.campos = {}
        self.guardar = False
        linea = 0
        for campo in campos:
            etiqueta, tipo, valor, modo = campo
            self.campos[etiqueta] = Campo(padre, linea,
                                      etiqueta, tipo, valor, modo)
            linea += 1
        self.btnacep = tk.Button(padre, text="Aceptar", command=self.aceptar)
        self.btncanc = tk.Button(padre, text="Cancelar", command=self.cancelar)
        self.btnacep.grid(column=1, row=linea, sticky='W')
        self.btncanc.grid(column=1, row=linea, sticky='E')

    def aceptar(self):
        self.guardar = True
        self.padre.destroy()

    def cancelar(self):
        self.padre.destroy()




class BFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, img, *args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args)

        self.imagen = Image.open(img)
        self.copia_imagen= self.imagen.copy()
        self.imagen_de_fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagen)

        self.fondo = tk.Label(self, image=self.imagen_de_fondo)
        self.fondo.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.fondo.bind('<Configure>', self._redimensionar)

    def _redimensionar(self,event):
        ancho = event.width
        alto = event.height
        self.imagen = self.copia_imagen.resize((ancho, alto))
        self.imagen_de_fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagen)
        self.fondo.configure(image =  self.imagen_de_fondo)


class MyApp():
    def __init__(self, raiz):
        raiz.geometry('1364x700+0+0')
        #Fondo sólido (puedes usar los valores rgb en hexadecimal)
        raiz.configure(bg = "#FFB266")
        raiz.title('Dr. Juan Suarez')
        form_frame = BFrame(raiz, "fondo.jpg")
        form_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=100, pady = 100, expand=True)

        form = Formulario(form_frame, [["Nombre", "entry", "", False],
                                       ["Direccion", "entry", "", False],
                                       ["CC:","entry","", False],
                                       ["Tipo", "combobox", ['O+', 'O-','B', 'AB','A-','A+'], True],
                                       ["Numero", "entry", "(+57)", False]
                                       ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    raiz = tk.Tk()
    app = MyApp(raiz)
    raiz.mainloop()
```

Ejemplo en funcionamiento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no quieres esos labels con su propio fondo(que sean transparentes) tenemos otro problema que merece otra pregunta. Tkinter no soporta labels con fondo transparente. Para colocar texto y que de fondo se vea el fondo del widget padre hay que olvidarse de `Label` y recurrir a `Canvas`.

> **Aviso:** Usar `from Tkinter import *` es una mala práctica en Python (importar módulos de esta forma es peligroso en proyectos grandes, ineficiente en uso de memoria y dificulta la lectura del código por terceros). Usa `import Tkinter as tk` en su lugar.

---

> **Importante:** las variables que almacena la imagen deben mantenerse vivas y haciendo referencia a la imagen  mientras el fondo deba mostrarse. Tkinter no crea una referencia a la imagen, por lo que si la variable donde cargamos nuestra imagen es destruida por el GC el fondo queda en blanco.