# Ventana con fondo

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Comunidad tengo un pequeño problema, quiero que la ventana que me aparece cuando yo abro paciente tenga una imagen de fondo, ahi comenté mis fallidos intentos. Gracias

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def abrir():
    win=tk.Tk()
    win.geometry("1000x670+0+0")
    win.title("Agregar Paciente")
    win.configure(background='white')
    boton=tk.Button(win,text='Guardar',command=win.destroy)
    boton.place(x=500,y=200)

    ##############INTENTOS PARA COLOCAR IMAGEN ACA#####
    imagen = Image.open("fondo2.gif")
    copia_imagen=imagen.copy()
    imagen_de_fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
    fondo = tk.Label(image=imagen_de_fondo)
    fondo.place(x=0, y=0)

    image = Image.open("fondo2.gif")
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = Label(image=photo)
    label.image = photo # keep a reference!
    label.pack()
    ###################################################

    #image=tk.PhotoImage(file="fondo2.gif")
    #label=tk.label(image=image)
    #label.pack()
    #fondo2=PhotoImage(file="paciente.gif")
    #lblImagen2=Label(ventAbrir,image=fondo2).place(x=0,y=0)
    #ventAbrir.mainloop()
    win.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    win.mainloop()

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("1000x670+0+0")
ventana.title("Centro Medico Ultimo Suspiro")
fondo=PhotoImage(file="fondo2.gif")
lblImagen=Label(ventana,image=fondo).place(x=0,y=0)
##Creando menu

#Crear la barra de menu
barramenu=Menu(ventana)
#Crear los menus
menuHacer=Menu(barramenu)
#comandos de los menus
menuHacer.add_command(label="Agregar paciente",command=abrir)
menuHacer.add_command(label="Modificar paciente")
menuHacer.add_command(label="Eliminar paciente")
menuHacer.add_separator()
menuHacer.add_command(label="Salir",command=ventana.destroy)
#siguiente menu
menuHisto=Menu(barramenu)
menuHisto.add_command(label="Ver historia de paciente")
menuHisto.add_command(label="Ver citas por fecha")
#nxt
menuInfo=Menu(barramenu)
menuInfo.add_command(label="Acerca del software")
menuInfo.add_command(label="Instrucciones de uso")
#Agregar los menus a la barra
barramenu.add_cascade(label="Pacientes",menu=menuHacer)
barramenu.add_cascade(label="Informacion",menu=menuHisto)
barramenu.add_cascade(label="Ayuda",menu=menuInfo)
#Que la barra de menu este en la ventana
ventana.config(menu=barramenu)
ventana.resizable(width=False, height=False)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: JPSuarezQ  no se si has visto la respuesta que te dejé a tu pregunta anterior sobre el tema, no hay mucho más sobre los fondos en Tkinter que decir. Tu primer intento es el bueno (para una imagen con el tamaño exacto de la ventana , que sea gif y que la ventana no se pueda redimensionar). El problema es que tienes dos ventanas principales con dos mainloop(), eso no se debe hacer en Tkinter y prácticamente en ningún framework. Tal y como está diseñado Tkinter solo puede haber un mainloop por aplicación. Si quieres ventanas nuevas usa TopLevel.

Comment: De necio segui buscando si se podria de alguna forma pero opte por realizarllo de esta manera, le colocare un color de fondo a abrir......aunque me surge una pregunta, sucede que <ventana> es lo primero que veo, si utilizo TopLevel en <abrir> tengo que cerrar a <ventana> 1. Como hago para que luego de hacer algo en <abrir> pueda volver a <ventana>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te comenté, no se pueden tener más de un `mainloop` en una aplicación de Tkinter. Este ciclo infinito es el encargado de estar constantemente redibujando nuestra GUI y solo puede haber uno por aplicación y no debe bloquearse nunca.

Esto es común a otros frameworks gráficos como Kivy, Qt, Gtk, etc. En cada uno se provee de algún recurso para crear ventanas secundarias. En el caso de Tkinter esto se hace con `Toplevel`. Recuerda que `TopLevel` **necesita que le pases la ventana principal como primer argumento.**

Además de esto, tu creas tu ventana secundaria llamando a una función. Para que el fondo se mantenga la imágen **debe tener siempre una referencia** o el recolector de basura la elimina de memoria y no se verá la imágen de fondo.

Te aconsejo que para crear interfaces gráficas uses programación orientada a objetos, te facilitará mucho la tarea. No obstante, para hacerlo sin POO lo más simple es crear una referencia permanente a la imágen en la ventana principal y pasarsela como argumento a la función (también puedes usar variables globales, pero usando argumentos queda más legible y segura).

Este sería tu código usando dos imágenes diferentes, una como fondo de la ventana principal y otra como fondo de la secundaria (**no te olvides de cambiar las rutas de las imágenes** por las tuyas):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def abrir(parent, img_fondo):
    win=tk.Toplevel(parent)
    win.geometry("1000x670+0+0")
    win.title("Agregar Paciente")
    win.configure(background='white')
    boton=tk.Button(win,text='Guardar',command=win.destroy)
    boton.place(x=500,y=200)

    fondo = tk.Label(win, image=img_fondo)
    fondo.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    win.resizable(width=False, height=False)


ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("1000x670+0+0")
ventana.title("Centro Medico Ultimo Suspiro")

#Fondo ventana principal
imagen = Image.open("fondo_principal.jpg")        #<<<<<<<< Cambiar
imagen_de_fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
fondo = tk.Label(ventana, image=imagen_de_fondo)
fondo.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
#Imagen para fondo de ventana secundaria
img_2 = Image.open("fondo_secundaria.jpg")        #<<<<<<<< Cambiar
img2_fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_2)

##Creando menu
#Crear la barra de menu
barramenu=tk.Menu(ventana)
#Crear los menus
menuHacer=tk.Menu(barramenu)
#comandos de los menus
menuHacer.add_command(label="Agregar paciente",command=lambda: abrir(ventana, img2_fondo))
menuHacer.add_command(label="Modificar paciente")
menuHacer.add_command(label="Eliminar paciente")
menuHacer.add_separator()
menuHacer.add_command(label="Salir",command=ventana.destroy)
#siguiente menu
menuHisto=tk.Menu(barramenu)
menuHisto.add_command(label="Ver historia de paciente")
menuHisto.add_command(label="Ver citas por fecha")
#nxt
menuInfo=tk.Menu(barramenu)
menuInfo.add_command(label="Acerca del software")
menuInfo.add_command(label="Instrucciones de uso")
#Agregar los menus a la barra
barramenu.add_cascade(label="Pacientes",menu=menuHacer)
barramenu.add_cascade(label="Informacion",menu=menuHisto)
barramenu.add_cascade(label="Ayuda",menu=menuInfo)
#Que la barra de menu este en la ventana
ventana.config(menu=barramenu)
ventana.resizable(width=False, height=False)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Las imágenes no se redimensionan por lo que tienen que tener el tamaño de la ventana exacto. Puedes redimensionarlas mediante PIL:

```
imagen = Image.open("fondo_principal.jpg")
imagen_de_fondo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
imgen_de_fondo = imagen_de_fondo.resize((ancho, alto))
```

Si quieres que ajuste de forma automática el tamaño al redimesionar la ventana, mírate el ejemplo de mi respuesta en tu pregunta anterior: [Poner fondos de ventana en Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81845/15089).

Comment: Como lo comente en la anterior, hasta ahora me introduzco en este mundo y me falta para entender POO, igual ahí voy avanzando, muchas gracias por responder a  mis inquietudes.